# Metro class library, FileInfo replacement?

Tags: c#, io, windows-runtime

In one of our components ported from Java to C#, we used [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) as an equivalent for Java's [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class.

Now we're working towards making that class library available to Metro applications and we have to pass the certification obviously.

What's a good replacement for `FileInfo` in .NET Framework 4.5 core profile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [StorageFile Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.aspx) in the [Windows.Storage Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.aspx).

> **StorageFile class**
>
> Represents a file. Provides information about the file and its content, and ways to manipulate them.

*Example:*

```
var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(path);
```

Comment: That's what I thought. Does it make sense to replace `FileInfo` with `StorageFile` when targeting Windows 8 Desktop? I'm asking because `FileInfo` is still supported in .NET 4.5

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the FileInfo class is not available in Metro apps, and the StorageFile class not available in non-Metro apps. But I can't check right now.

Comment: Most of the System.IO Classes like Directory, FileInfo are not available in Metro Apps but available in standard .NET Framework 4.5..
I experienced this problem while creating a Standard ClassLib, by mistake I chose the ClassLibrary for Metro Apps!

Answer (score 0):

in order to target both win8 platform and silverlight. that is for metro apps and non metro apps in your case just create a shared file project and put in #if conditions. so that it targets for both the platform.
have a look in the following link for creating the same

http://www.dotnetjalps.com/2015/02/shared-project-visual-studio-2015.html